# Copying Dynamic Table Column with rows of Hidden style properties to textarea jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I'm pretty new to jQuery and I'm having a little trouble accomplishing a specific function that I want for my table.

I have a db list that gets dynamically sorted and I want to be able to create a textarea that includes the text from a specific column on the click of the column header.  I have some of the functionality from the code that I used from this http://jsfiddle.net/4BwGG/3/ but here are some things I just can't figure out:

I have some of the rows in my table hidden using `style="display: none"` property within the `<tr>` tag and when the script parses everything, the information from those hidden rows get included too. How do I do a check so that only the displayed rows are copied to the text area?

Here is what one row entry looks like:

```
<tr filtermatch="false" style="display: none;">
  <td>< a href="http://example.edu">Tommy Trojan< /a>< /td>   
  < td>123-555-1231< /td>
  < td>Statue Man< /td>
  < td>[LTS1] [LTS2] [PM] [PM2] [TA1] [TA2] < /td>
  < td>tommy@example.edu< /td>
< /tr>`
```

Here is the Function:

```
function SelectColumn(index, tableId) {
    var columnText = 'You selected:\n\n';
    var columnSelector = '#' + tableId + ' tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')';
    var cells = $(columnSelector);

    // clear existing selections
    if (window.getSelection) { // all browsers, except IE before version 9
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }


    if (document.createRange) {
        cells.each(function(i, cell) {
            var rangeObj = document.createRange();
            rangeObj.selectNodeContents(cell);
            window.getSelection().addRange(rangeObj);
            columnText = columnText + '\n' + rangeObj.toString();
        });
    }
    else { // Internet Explorer before version 9
        cells.each(function(i, cell) {
            var rangeObj = document.body.createTextRange();
            rangeObj.moveToElementText(cell);
            rangeObj.select();
            columnText = columnText + '\n' + rangeObj.toString();
        });
    }

    alert(columnText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the code in a conditional statement that checks the visibility of the `tr`.

For example:

```
if (document.createRange) {
    cells.each(function(i, cell) {
        if ($(cell).closest('tr').is(':visible')) {
            var rangeObj = document.createRange();
            rangeObj.selectNodeContents(cell);
            window.getSelection().addRange(rangeObj);
            columnText = columnText + '\n' + rangeObj.toString();
        }
    });
}
```

Of course, you'd want to do the same thing in the else block as well. But for the record, that jsFiddle did not work for me in IE7 (it throws an error about unsupported property or method).

I know you didn't ask, but unless you need the column to actually be *selected*, I would refactor the code. If you want the column to *appear* selected, I'd probably add a little CSS.

Someone else could probably improve the code even more. But here is my suggestion. I've added comments to explain what I did and why.

```
function SelectColumn(index, tableId) {
    // cache the table selector in a local variable
    // because we are going to use it more than once
    var columnText = 'You selected:\n\n',
        table = $('#' + tableId),
        cells = table.find('td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')');

    // reset the background color of all cells
    table.find('td').css('background-color', '#fff');

    cells.each(function(i, cell) {
        // turn cell into a jQuery object and cache it
        // because we are going to use it more than once
        cell = $(cell);

        if (cell.closest('tr').is(':visible')) {
            // get the cell text and trim it
            // because different browsers treat newlines differently
            columnText += $.trim(cell.text()) + '\n';

            // set a background color on the selected cells
            cell.css('background-color', '#ccc');
        }
    });

    alert(columnText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery it will make things very easy.
To select only visible elements you can use :visible in jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var textAreaContent=[];
    $('tr:visible').each(function(){
        var content=$('<div />').append($(this).clone()).html();
        textAreaContent.push(content);
    });
    $('.textarea').val(textAreaContent.join(''));
});
```

check on jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/sudhanshu414/9YeLm/](http://jsfiddle.net/sudhanshu414/9YeLm/1)

Other option of selecting is using filter. This can also be useful if you want to filter on some other condition.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var textAreaContent=[]; 
    $('tr').filter(function(){ return $(this).css('display')!='none';}).each(function(){
        var content=$('<div />').append($(this).clone()).html();
        textAreaContent.push(content);
    });
    $('.textarea').val(textAreaContent.join(''));
});
```

Jsfiddle : [http://jsfiddle.net/sudhanshu414/3GfqN/](http://jsfiddle.net/sudhanshu414/3GfqN/1)